# Deploying web services with different environment variables in the frontend

Tags: docker, webpack, continuous-integration, environment-variables, continuous-deployment

I have a web service which consists of a backend and a forntend, and in the frontend I use an API uri which can change depending on the environment the service is being deployed to.

Using [webpack's EnvironmentPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx) I can build the source code simply with other environment variables. The plugin allows me to use `process.env` in javascript which is convenient in the development phase but after bundling the frontend's code `process.env` will remain the same with the given environment variables when bundled.

The issue is that on the CI pipelines I build a docker image for the web service but I don't know the API uri until deploying it later on.

How can I effectively change the API uri based on environment variables?

Comment: Assuming you want the environment variables established and passed in when starting I have answered the question.  if not please modify your post to add more details.

Comment: @LhasaDad I editted the question to clarify myself

Comment: So sounds like your cooking in the uri rather than having it parameterized.  would it be possible to build your docker image with an entrypoint that is a script and have the script check the environment and then use that info to modify a config file that has the URI in it?  just a thought.

Comment: @LhasaDad that's exactly what I'd like to do, I'm just not sure how to.

Comment: ah, ok, now we are getting somewhere.   So one of the things you have in your dockerfile is the ability to declare the entry item.  with that you can do something like: 1) set environment data via the docker run cmdline (via answer I gave)  2), in the script get the environment info and finally, use it in the script to modify whatever file contains the uri data using something like sed.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for passing environment variables  one is via a file

```
docker run --env-file ./env.list ubuntu bash
```

The other is via the command line with the -e option to the docker run command.  you can stack the -e option to pass more than one environment variable.

one of the things you have in your dockerfile is the ability to declare the entry item. with that you can do something like:

1. set environment data via the docker run cmdline (via info above)
2. in the script get the environment info
3. finally, use it in the  script to modify whatever file contains the uri data using something like sed

Comment: The problem is that the environment variables are being bundled when I run webpack which is prior to deplyment.